# how to copy windows directory without damaging it?

Tags: windows-7, windows

1- I have a drive image of Windows drive.

2- I want to copy the windows directory from inside that image drive back into the drive where windows was installed.(the former windows dir has been deleted)

3- I run my laptop using a live windows and can mount the drive image into Z:\

4- how can I copy the Windows dir to its original drive without losing anything? I want it to be like the original one considering symbolic links and permissions and etc

5- Consider that I am doing it for Win 7 and above

Any viable solutions?

Answer (score 0):

your easy choice is to detach your hard drive and connect it to another system then copy entire windows file.

other solution is boot your system with **hirenbootcd**
and use mini-xp tool it gives you full permission of disk files